# FETCH_ERROR "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL" for requests made in tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query, vitest, msw

This is the first time when I setup test environment with [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) and mock server ([msw](https://mswjs.io/)). Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

#### Environment

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| msw | 1.2.1 |
| react | 18 |
| redux toolkit | 1.9.3 |
| vitest | 0.29.3 |
| cross-fetch | 3.1.5 |
| typescript | 5 |
| NodeJS | 18 (also tried 19.3) |
| OS | Windows |

#### Mock server and request handlers

```
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('http://localhost:5173/api/search/photos', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(resList));
  }),
  rest.get('http://localhost:5173/api/photos/ZJIwrGrQb2Y', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(resPhoto));
  }),
];

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
```

Then in setupTests.ts file this mock server starts before we run tests

```
import { beforeAll, afterEach, afterAll } from 'vitest';
import { setupStore } from '../redux/store';
import { apiSlice } from '../redux/api';

const store = setupStore({});

beforeAll(() =>
  server.listen({
    onUnhandledRequest: 'error',
  })
);

afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
  store.dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());
});

afterAll(() => server.close());
```

#### RTK Query Requests

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders(headers) {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      headers.set('Accept-Version', 'v1');
      headers.set('Authorization', `Client-ID ${API_ACCESS_TOKEN}`);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    return {
      getPhotoList: builder.query<TransformedApiResponse, RequestParams>({
        query: (params: RequestParams) => {
          const { query } = params;
          return `/search/photos?query=${query}`;
        },
        transformResponse: (response: ApiResponse): TransformedApiResponse => ({
          total: response.total,
          totalPages: response.total_pages,
          cards: response.results.map((item: PhotoDTO): CardData => {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              imgSrc: item.urls.small,
              alt: item.alt_description,
              likes: item.likes,
            };
          }),
        }),
      }),
      getOnePhoto: builder.query<FullPhotoDTO, string>({
        query: (id: string) => {
          return `/photos/${id}`;
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});

export const { useGetPhotoListQuery, useGetOnePhotoQuery } = apiSlice;
```

#### Vite config

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), eslint()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      all: true,
    },
    setupFiles: ['./src/test/setupTests.ts'],
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://api.unsplash.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

#### Test code

```
describe('App test', () => {
  test('Should render home page', async () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText(/Home Page/i)).toBeDefined();

    expect(screen.getByRole('loader')).toBeDefined();

    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByRole('loader'));

    expect(screen.getByText('1113')).toBeDefined();
  });
```

#### Current behavior

The above test fails:

[image]

I display network errors on the page, so I can see this in HTML:

[image]

Requests made in the main application are working fine (tested on localhost). So I'm sure that RTK query code is good. Requests made from tests all fail with `FETCH_ERROR "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL"`. Before migrating to redux and RTK query, I was using a simple `fetch` and I also remember that there was a very similar error (`Invalid URL null` or something). That time I solved it by importing `fetch` from `cross-fetch`. This time I've tried to do the same, but the error persists.

#### What I tried?

1. import `fetch` from `cross-fetch` (as recommended on GitHub and StackOverflow)

   ```
   import { fetch, Headers, Request, Response } from 'cross-fetch'

   global.fetch = fetch
   global.Headers = Headers
   global.Request = Request
   global.Response = Response
   ```
2. Tried alternative libraries: whatwg-fetch, isomorphic-fetch.
3. I also tried to remove vite proxy server, just to simplify things and localize the problem, but it didn't help anyway.
4. I tried to move `server.listen()` call from setupTests.ts to each individual test file.
5. I added logging to my Home component. This is how I got a more detailed error message, at least.

   ```
   const { query } = useAppSelector((state) => state.home);

   const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetPhotoListQuery({ query: query });
   console.table({ data, isFetching, error });
   ```

   [image]

I don't know how to verify that my mock server (msw) is up and ready to accept requests.

Comment: Have you made sure that your `BASE_URL` is a full url with a leading `http://`?

Comment: @phry yes, I specify protocol like `export const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5173/api';`

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

I had the same problem today and could solve it by just replacing the global `location` property.
MSW internally constructs an URL object with your requested url and as a second parameter the current origin.
`happy-dom` emulates the location API but sets the `origin` property to `null`. Therefore the following call produces the Invalid URL error (made by MSW internally):

```
const requestUrl = new URL(
       url,
       typeof location !== 'undefined' ? location.origin : undefined
     )
```

This is also the reason why you had the error mentioning some `null` value when you used fetch. For example I am only using the fetch API for requests and that's why I get the plain error produced by node. Your error is extended I guess because of the framework you are using for the requests.

### Solution

Just use the location API methods like `location.replace(url)` or `location.assign(url)` to have your `origin` set correctly:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    location.replace(`http://localhost`);    
})
```

**Note** that I'm using vitests `beforeEach` hook which wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: this could be interesting - where is location?

Comment: @aronchick The location property is attached to the Document and Window interfaces. Therefore it's also globally defined. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) you can learn more about the Location API.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in MSW v2.1.5. Make sure to always update to the latest version (`npm i msw@latest`).

src: [release notes](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/releases/tag/v2.1.5).